# OpenVPN server on VPS no internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to get a simple OpenVPN server set up on a cheap Vultr vps through docker-compose.

I was able to generate certificates and such just fine, and can even connect to the server..

But when I try to connect to it on my mac through Tunnelblick, I have no internet.  My IPv6 internet works, but seems to just be using my home internet, not the VPN tunnel.

Whenever I try to connect to any IPv4 traffic, it times out.  Even trying `ping 8.8.8.8` gives me a timeout error.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  openvpn:
    container_name: openvpn
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
    network_mode: host
    ports:
    - "943:943"
    - "1194:1194/udp"
    privileged: true
    hostname: example.com
    volumes:
    - /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro
    - /etc/openvpn:/etc/openvpn

volumes:
  openvpn-config:
    name: openvpn-config
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be related to DNS nameserver settings not being pushed to clients. You can try manually assigning a nameserver (e.g. 8.8.8.8) in Tunnelblick.

As for IPv6 traffic not being encapsulated, I'd check if the docker engine is configured to handle such traffic. It looks like Kylemanna's image needs additional configuration (e.g. add --ipv6 when starting the Docker daemon) as explained at [IPv6 Support](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/blob/master/docs/ipv6.md)